# I need to add value in customer table after successful order placed

Tags: magento2, database, customer-attribute, transaction

This is my Installdata.php Which saves the cashback value in attribute Id.
Now I need to save this value into customer table of magento 2 if transaction is successful.

```
<?php

namespace Rk\Wallet\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;
    public function __construct(
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
    )
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'cashback', [
            'group' => 'Product Details',
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'sort_order' => 102,
            'backend' => '',
            'frontend' => '',
            'label' => 'CashBack Percentage',
            'input' => 'text',
            'class' => 'cash',
            'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
            'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'default' => '',
            'searchable' => true,
            'filterable' => true,
            'comparable' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => true,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'unique' => false,
            'apply_to' => 'simple,configurable,virtual,bundle,downloadable'
        ]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'cashback_validity', [
            'group' => 'Cashback/Delivery Date',
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'sort_order' => 102,
            'backend' => '',
            'frontend' => '',
            'label' => 'Cashback validity Days',
            'input' => 'text',
            'class' => '',
            'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
            'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'default' => '',
            'searchable' => true,
            'filterable' => true,
            'comparable' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => true,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'unique' => false,
            'apply_to' => 'simple,configurable,virtual,bundle,downloadable'
        ]);
    }

}
```